# Android SQLite Transaction, two datasources

Tags: android, sqlite, transactions

im having doubts on how to procede with database manipulation using Begin Transaction

I have 2 data source objects: ClientDataSource and MovementsDataSource

each of theres has its own SQLitedabase object which is set with the Open() method with sets its database private Object with a Writable Database.

Now, i have to send the Records from the Movements Table to a server and then ask for the updated Clients from the same server.

Inside my class i first Send the new Movements, then if sucessful, delete all clients from the SQLite, and finally retrieve the new Updated Clients from the server and insert them into the database.

each data source has a Get() method for obtainting their respective Database Object, BUT it is in fact the same database they are operating and I am not sure of how to use the BaginTransction, Endtransaction methods to ensure data consistency

this is the code from the Async Task

```
@Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... url) {

            try {
                clientDataSource.open();
                movementDataSource.open();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                //Treat SQL Exception
            }

            try {
                if(sendMovements()) {
                    clientDataSource.deleteAllClients();
                }
                updateDatabase(url[0]);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                //Treat Json Exception
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //Treat IOException
            }

            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

i have to give one example then how begintransaction works...

```
public static void Insert(ArrayList<Model_CategoryMaster> categoryMasters) {
        SQLiteDatabase sqldb = EGLifeStyleApplication.sqLiteDatabase;
        sqldb.beginTransaction();
        for (Model_CategoryMaster model : categoryMasters) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(CATEGORY_ID, model.Category_Id);
            values.put(CATEGORYNAME, model.CategoryName);
            values.put(DESCRIPTION, model.Description);
            values.put(ISACTIVE, model.IsActive);
            values.put(CREATEDON, model.CreatedOn);
            values.put(CREATEDBY, model.CreatedBy);
            values.put(UPDATEDON, model.UpdatedOn);
            values.put(UPDATEDBY, model.UpdatedBy);
            values.put(ISDELETED, model.IsDeleted);
            values.put(DELETEDON, model.DeletedOn);
            values.put(DELETEDBY, model.DeletedBy);
            values.put(PK_CATEGORYMASTER, model.PK_CategoryMaster);
            if (!CommonMethod.CheckIsDataAlreadyInDBorNot(Table_Name,
                    CATEGORY_ID, model.Category_Id)) {
                sqldb.insert(Table_Name, null, values);
            } else {
                sqldb.update(Table_Name, values, "Category_Id=?",
                        new String[] { model.Category_Id });
            }
        }
        sqldb.setTransactionSuccessful();
        sqldb.endTransaction();
    }// End insert method
```

begin transaction means data will get arraylist then db will open one time and sql.begintansaction() use to get faster database operation.because db is not open or close more times.

Comment: should i simply all beginTransaction() one time and then at end endTransaction..???.

Comment: like, clientDataSource.getDatabse().beginTransaction()

Comment: and then at the end clientDataSource.getDatabase().endTransaction() ,,, dont minding the movement datasource??

Comment: i mean,, i know how to use the Transaction methods, i simply dont know how to apply themn in this case

Comment: why are you open two table at a time?

Comment: because i need to send movements and mark them (update) as "Sent" and then update the CLients records